# I am using opencv 4.5.5 and I am getting this error but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: c++, opencv

vector filtered_finger_points;

```
if (filtered_far_points.size() > 1) {
    vector<Point> finger_points;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < filtered_start_points.size(); i++) {
        vector<Point> closest_points = findClosestOnX(filtered_far_points, filtered_start_points[i]);
        
        if (isFinger(closest_points[0], filtered_start_points[i], closest_points[1], LIMIT_ANGLE_INF, LIMIT_ANGLE_SUP, center_bounding_rect, bounding_rectangle.height * BOUNDING_RECT_FINGER_SIZE_SCALING))
            finger_points.push_back(filtered_start_points[i]);
    }
```

i don't know how to fix it it says error at finger_points"."push_back;

this is the error:
`no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::vector<cv::Point, std::allocator<cv::Point>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point, std::allocator<cv::Point>>>]" matches the argument list`

Comment: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/handy/blob/master/Handy/FingerCount.cpp

Comment: make sure your source code is displayed correctly. and what's that `"."` in your last sentence supposed to mean? -- and what is the error? don't just say there's an error, show us the message -- please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow
this is the error "no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::vector<cv::Point, std::allocator<cv::Point>>, _Alloc=" std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point, std::allocator<cv::Point>>>]" matches the argument list"

Comment: ok so this is a typical C++ compiler error message. you'll need to learn how to debug C++, and how to interpret these error messages. the issue here is wrong types. -- now you need to show the definition of `filtered_start_points`. -- the first line of your code isn't in the code block. please look after that.